# How to retrieve the authenticated user in Golang

Tags: go, jwt

```
func Login(c echo.Context) error {
    user := &users.User{}
    if err := c.Bind(&user); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return token.SigIn(c, user.Email, user.Password)
}
```

This is my Login function that retrieve the token when the user send the requests.

the Signin func that handle the token

```
func SigIn(c echo.Context, email, password string) error {
    user := users.User{}

    db := database.SetUp()

    if err := db.Where("email = ?", email).First(&user).Error; gorm.IsRecordNotFoundError(err) {

        restErr := errors.NewBadRequestError("Invalid credentials")

        return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, restErr)
    }

    if user.VerifyPassword(password) != nil {
        restErr := errors.NewUnauthorizedError("Couldn't log you in with these credentials")

        return c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, restErr)
    }

    //user is successfull

    return CreateToken(c)
}
```

the CreateToken func is as follow

```
type TokenJWT struct {
    Token string `json:"token"`
}

func CreateToken(c echo.Context) error {
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)

    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    claims["authorized"] = true
    claims["name"] = "Pascal Gaetan"
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 1).Unix()

    // Generate encoded token and send it as response.
    t, err := token.SignedString([]byte("my_secret_key"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, TokenJWT{
        Token: t,
    })
}
```

when everyhting is succesfull, i would like to get the authenticated user through an URL /api/me that calls a Me function

Comment: In your `SignIn` function, I see: `db := database.SetUp()`. Is that _connecting_ to the DB? If so: you're never closing/releasing the connection, and reconnecting to the DB for each request is stupendously wasteful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me split your question into two parts: the first one is how to easily encode and decode user in or from JWT token and the second part is how to write a generic code which can retrieve user from everywhere.

From your example I mentioned that you created a MapClaims but to reduce parsing complexity it will be better to create a token using a custom claims type. If you are using dgrijalva/jwt-go, then according to documentation you can do something like that

```
type UserClaims struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

// encode it as before, but with your created type 
t := jwt.New(signer)
userClaims := &UserClaims{Name: "Burmese"}
t.Claims = userClaims
tokenString, err = t.SignedString(]byte("my_secret_key"))
```

then you can parse your user in your router/framework middleware with

```
tokenString := "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJleHAiOjE1MDAwLCJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0In0.HE7fK0xOQwFEr4WDgRWj4teRPZ6i3GLwD5YCm6Pwu_c"

token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &UserClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte("my_secret_key"), nil
})

if claims, ok := token.Claims.(*UserClaims); ok && token.Valid {
    fmt.Printf("%v %v", claims.Name, claims.StandardClaims.ExpiresAt)
} else {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

This example was adopted from an official documentation [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#ParseWithClaims)

Now you know how to parse authenticated user struct with ease and the next logic move is to wrap it into your middleware. Whether there are a lot of implementation details like you can retrieve JWT from cookie, header or query, also defining some ordering on them, the gist the following: you should have wrapped abovementioned code into your middleware and after parsing the struct you can pass it via your request context. I don't use echo and other frameworks, but for pure net/http you can pass your parsed struct from middleware with

```
context.WithValue(ctx, UserCtxKey, claims)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Olegs. It really helped me. I just had to use the custom claim

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common design pattern to create an authenticated client and then call various action methods on it. You could do something like the following:

```
type Client struct {
    ... // other members
    token string // unexported unless there is a special reason to do otherwise
}

func NewClient(c echo.Context, email, password string) (*Client, error) {
    user := users.User{}
    cl := Client{}
    ... // your original method
    cl.token = token
    return &cl, nil
}

func (c *Client) DoSomething(...) ... { ... }
```